# Define an array and pass each point 2 values?

Tags: java

I want to define a grid in which I specify an (x,y) coordinate for each point in the grid. So I want to do something like this:

```
int [][] pt;    
for (x=0; x<numX; x=x+1) {
  for (y=0; y<numY; y=y+1) {
    pt[x][y] = {xval, yval};
  }
}
```

The reason why is because I am mapping the values of an orderly grid to a disorderly grid. The above code of course causes an exception (unexpected token "{").

What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do. Why are you trying to store the coordinates at the same indices? Where do xval and yval come from?

Comment: you have to put in [x][y] one value, that's why is complaining if you want to put a tuple consider using another array type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things:

- You havent initialized your array (maybe you did just didnt put in code)
- You are trying to put two values into a place where only one can be held.

Initialize your array like this (if you didnt)

```
int[][] pt = new int[numX][numY];
```

To store both values in the array you will need to use an object. The java [Point](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html) class would be an example of something you could use

```
Point[][] pt = new Point[numX][numY];
for (x=0; x<numX; x=x+1) {
   for (y=0; y<numY; y=y+1) {
       pt[x][y] = new Point(xval, yval);;
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I just didn't show the code on initialization. But I didn't know about the point class. Thanks, that's a good solution!

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to store a fixed number of values inside every array cell?
Then you are limited with 2 major cases:

1. Use an object
   Java doesn't have user defined value types, so you are forced to use full-blown objects on the heap (with little hope that JVM will be very clever and optimize it, but chances are near zero), be it an array, or any other class.
2. If both of your values are less than 64 bits, you can pack them in built-in primitive type (such as `long`) using bitwise arithmetic. (**You must be very careful here**)

`int`s are 32 bit, so you can pack 2 `int`s in 1 `long`.

Comment: That's clever! But I think the Point class mentioned above will be more robust.

Comment: @lynvie And less efficient both in speed and memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

`pt[x][y] = {xval, yval}` is illegal, `pt[][]` is a double dimensional array. It only can store one value. Just like this `pt[x][y] = value`

You may try java map.